# I need a regex for Number,Space and Special Character

Tags: regex

I need a regex for Number,Space and Special Character. Here are my examples:

`+44 161 999 8888`

`011 44 (161) 999 8888`

`1-408-999 8888`

`+1 (408) 999 8888`

`222 8888`

`1-212-222 8888`

`+1 (212) 222 8888`

`+1 212 999 8888`

`001 (212) 999 8888`

`0161 999 8888`

`+44 (161) 999 8888`

`2222 8888`

`01-2222 8888`

`+44 1-2222 8888`

`+91-80-26584050`

`26584050`

Comment: I need fax Numbers Regex but overall nation

Comment: This is a huge number of patterns to match.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes I trying last one hour. I'm Not expert of regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[0-9 ()\+\-]+$
```

The [] means the items in this set.

The + on the end means one or more of them.

The 0-9 means numbers in this range.

The space means a space character.

The ( and ) mean the parentheses characters

The + and - mean the plus and minus characters.

The ^ at the start and $ at the end say this is the complete statement from start to finish, with nothing else in between.

I think that covers your complete set

Comment: Thank You but I dont need Letters(a-z or A-Z).

Comment: Ah I see.  I've updated the answer, so now only the characters that you are interested in will match.

Answer (score 1):

for example in php:

```
<?php
$input = "+44 161 999 8888";

//$input = "011 44 (161) 999 8888";

//$input = "1-408-999 8888";

//$input = "+1 (408) 999 8888";

//$input = "222 8888";

//$input = "0161 999 8888";

//$input = "01-2222 8888";

//$input = "+44 1-2222 8888";

//$input = "+91-80-26584050";

//$input = "26584050";


preg_match("/(^\+[0-9]+\ [0-9]+\ [0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|^[0-9]+\ [0-9]+\ \([0-9]+\)\ [0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|^[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|^\+?[0-9]+\ \([0-9]+\)\ [0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|^[0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|^[0-9]+\ [0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|^[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|^[0-9]+\ [0-9]+\-[0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|^\+[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+$|^\+[0-9]+\ [0-9]+\-[0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|^[0-9]+$)/", $input, $m);

echo $input;
print_r($m);
```

regex separated:

```
/(
^\+[0-9]+\ [0-9]+\ [0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|
^[0-9]+\ [0-9]+\ \([0-9]+\)\ [0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|
^[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|
^\+?[0-9]+\ \([0-9]+\)\ [0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|
^[0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|^[0-9]+\ [0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|
^[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|^[0-9]+\ [0-9]+\-[0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|
^\+[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+$|
^\+[0-9]+\ [0-9]+\-[0-9]+\ [0-9]+$|
^[0-9]+$)/
```

if you need specific lengh of the number, change "+" for {number} for example length of 4 chars {4}

```
[0-9]{4}
```